# How to find files greater than a size in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tree, find

I want to find user, size, modified date and full file path of all files in sub-directories starting from a dir. I have got to following so far:

```
nohup sudo \
tree /work/mydir \
-sufiD \
--noreport \
--timefmt="%Y-%m-%d" | \
sed -e 's/ \+/ /g' -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/\.\///g' -e 's/ /|/g' | \
tail -n+2 \
> usage_mydir.txt &
```

This gives me the desired output except that it lists **all** files; i want to filter out files say less than 10MB which will reduce my output file considerably (from over 500 MB to less than 5MB).

I am open to any other commands such as `find . -type f -size +10M`.
But I need the owner, size and last modified time of the file.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I believe that the downvoter thinks that your question is not about **programming**, but about **using** a Linux command. I rather think that a command of this complexity makes sense only inside a script, not interactively, and hence feel that the question is OK here. To address your problem: _I need the owner, size and last modified time_ : Did you consider running the `stat` command on the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-printf` option of `find` can print the owner (`%u`), size (`%s`), and modification time (`%t`).

```
find . -type f -size +10M -printf '%p %u %s %t\n'
```

Comment: how to format the time? i have see the man page of find; there is a %Tk option; but i'm not able to create a date format %Y-%m-%d using that..

Comment: @AbhishekJain: Use `%TY-%Tm-%Td`.